# Resize child div element to fit in parent div on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize, autoresize

I have a `div` element (*shown with red border in the image below*), which I want to be able to fit in its parent `div` when the window is resized and not fall into the next line (*the parent is the one with the green border*).

I want the red `div` to have a starting `width: 949px` (in my current screen) in order to fit the entire space available as shown in the image, but be resizable, so that it doesn't fall into the next line if `width: 949px` is to much to fit.

In essence, I want it at all costs to cover the area it covers in the image even if in a narrower screen that means it will be like `10px` wide.

How can I achieve this? Any solution using **CSS**, **JavaScript** or **jQuery** will be gladly accepted.

**The image**:

[image]

**CSS**:

```
#parent {
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: inline-block;
}

#child1-row2 {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 288px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#child2-row2 {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 288px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 25px 0 25px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#child3-row2 {/* The one with the red border */
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 452px;
    width: 949px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: can you please share your code ? CSS and HTML

Comment: for child elements use width as %

Comment: Do you mind if the child elements stack when width of the window is too small to contain them in one line?

Comment: add width in % for all 3 elements

Comment: @PratikDeshmukh I can't user percentages for all three children, since the first two must always have a fixed `height: 400px` and a fixed `width: 288px`

Comment: if it has fixed width: 288px, than how can those 3 elements fix in mobile device with width 320px ?

Comment: @PratikDeshmukh I don't care about mobiles. Just desktops and laptops.

Comment: see at bottom i have added window-resize code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function for this. [Support for calc](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) seems to be quite good now.

As you have mentioned, the left side divs are of fixed width, say 120px each. Also suppose the margin between them is 30px. So, the total width left for your red div is `100% - (2*120 + 2*30)px` i.e. (100% - 300px ).

```
#red-div
{
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
}
```

Comment: Why specifically `300px`?

Comment: @AngelPolitis Sorry, that depends on your layout. I have updated the answer to explain this.

Comment: Thanks for explaining @MohitBhardwaj. It works exactly as I want.

Answer (score 3):

You can use flexbox to do this by using the flex-grow property.

HTML :

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="box1">1</div>
  <div id="box2">2</div>
  <div id="box3">3</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#main {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row;
   width:100%;
   min-height:50px;
}
#box1{
    background-color:red; 
    width:100px; 
}
#box2{
    background-color:blue; 
    width:100px;
}
#box3{
    background-color:green;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jfjuep4y/)

Answer (score 0):

Add % width or you can do following :

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var window_width = $(window).width();
    var w1_width = $('.div1').width(); // The first element width
    var w2_width = $('.div2').width(); // The second element width
    var main_div_width = window_width - (w1_width+w2_width+gutter[i.e margin between all 3 elements]);
    $('.main_div_width').css('width', main_div_width);
});
```